# How to check a radio button based value from a group of radio buttons using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to create a star rating system for a person, for this user inputs value for five different categories and I want to show the average of those values on a group of radio buttons. I have obtained the average, but now not getting how to display the average.

```
$("input[name='overall']").each(function(){
                    if(this.value == response.average){
                        $(this).attr('checked', true); 
                    }
                });
```

I want to display the average over this field----

```
<div id="overall_rating" class="Clear">
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star {split:5} required" disabled="disbled" value="0.2" />
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="0.4"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="0.6"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="0.8"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="1.0"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="1.2"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="1.4"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="1.6"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="1.8"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="2.0"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="2.2"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="2.4"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="2.6"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="2.8"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="3.0"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="3.2"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="3.4"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="3.6"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="3.8"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="4.0"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="4.2"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="4.4"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="4.6"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="4.8"/>
<input id="overall" name="overall" type="radio" class="star" value="5.0"/>
</div>
```

Please help me find the solution to this problem.

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same id (probably not what's causing the issue, but you can't)

Comment: Are you sure `response.average` is available in that context?

Comment: try using .prop() rather than .attr() to check the radio button...

Comment: What do you mean "display the average over this field?"

Comment: Your code should be working, if `response.average` is really available: http://jsfiddle.net/eT5VF/

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code help you.

```
var average = response.average;

$("input[value='" + average + "']").attr("checked", "checked");
```

You just need to check if the response.average is contained in value attribute of one radio button.

Answer (score 0):

All of your input fields have the same ID. IDs have to be unique on a web page. Try correcting that first (i.e., remove the IDs from the inputs as you don't need them here).

Then try $(this).prop("checked", true);

Comment: TypeError: $(this).prop is not a function 

$(this).prop("checked", true);

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help. Actually the value of response.average was of string type, I have parsed that to float type and now the code is working. Thanks.